# Run a program when start an activity

Tags: fedora, kde-activities

Is there a way to run a program when specific activity starts on KDE 4.8.9?

PD.: KDE has a feature called Activity. It is designed for change your desktop settings. For example, KDE has some Activities by default like Desktop, Desktop Icons, Photos Activity, ... and each takes different Energy Saving Settings, wallpaper, ...

Comment: What sort of "activity" are we talking about here?